# Can you make Google OAuth 2.0 Access Token Last Longer?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-oauth

I'm trying to use FCM, which requires **OAuth 2.0 Access Token** from my Service Account. I use this token in my iOS app to send POST request to the **Apple Push Notification server**.

I just realized that OAuth 2.0 Access Token only lasts *3600 seconds*.

1. Can I make it last longer?
2. If not, how do request for new one using REST API so that I can automate it within my app?

I thought I had to create a custom key using my service account credentials (the same cred that I use to generate the OAuth 2.0 access token), and then use that to get a refresh token. While I do get a `refreshToken` and `idToken` (whatever the heck this is), it doesn't seem like the `refreshToken` or `idToken` is the same thing as the OAuth 2.0 access token.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on the exact integration you're using, but in general, you use refresh tokens to retrieve new access tokens.

If you're doing a typical OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code flow, you can exchange the refresh token as described here: [Refreshing an access token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline). In short: change the `grant_type` to `refresh_token` and include the refresh token in the `refresh_token` parameter.

However, if you're using a Service Account, you don't deal with refresh tokens at all. Instead, you can generate new access tokens using your Service Account Credentials as described here: [Preparing to make an authorized API call](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests).

You might consider using a managed OAuth service (like [Xkit](https://xkit.co), where I work) to handle this for you. That way you don't have to worry about the specifics of how new access tokens are generated and just keep building your app.

Comment: I manage to generate OAuth 2.0 access token using a python script, but I didn't realize that this access token expires after an hour. I can't be using the script to generate new access token every hour and then push an update for my iOS app every hour, so what I'm trying to figure out is how to get new access token, but within the scope of my iOS app, meaning I wouldn't want to use js, py, etc. If I can somehow use REST API to GET new acess token, then that would be the most ideal, unless there is a Firebase OAuth library for iOS that handles this for me.

Comment: There is a Firebase Authentication library for iOS: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin. If that doesn't work, you'll need to go through the OAuth flow on the device itself, here's Google's docs for that: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app